# Calling procedure in java with parameter

Tags: java, stored-procedures

I got stuck in using CallableStatement with a parameter which should change all salaries in the database.

Here is the procedure. Ratio isn't in the Employee class.

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE CHANGE_SALARY
    (ratio DECIMAL) AS
    BEGIN
    Update employee SET salary=round(salary/ratio);
    end;
```

couldn't find out how to implement. I need to get ratio from "field_getRatio" and send to procedure to apply all salaries.

```
    String sql = "{call change_salary(?)}";
    CallableStatement cStmt = dbConnection.prepareCall(sql);
    cStmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.DECIMAL);
    cStmt.execute();
```

Thanks for all your help.

Edit: Don't know why this post has been upvoted but the problem has been solved thanks to Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding `in` and `out` parameters.

This:

```
CallableStatement cStmt = dbConnection.prepareCall(sql);
cStmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.DECIMAL);
cStmt.execute();
```

Is declaring that your ratio parameter is an output from the procedure, but it's not.

You should be doing something like:

```
CallableStatement cStmt = dbConnection.prepareCall(sql);
cStmt.setObject(1, theRatio, Types.DECIMAL);
cStmt.execute();
```